# C# query extension in ThenInclude fails in separate method

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```cs
var events = await context.Events
    .Include(c => c.Location)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Settlement)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.SettlementNames.Where(c => c.LanguageId.Equals(1))
    .ToListAsync();
```

That runs correctly. But if I move the where query into a separate file, like this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereLanguageId<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, byte languageId) where T : ILanguageEntity
{
    return entity.Where(c => c.LanguageId.Equals(languageId));
}
```

And use `.ThenInclude(c => c.SettlementNames.WhereLanguageId(1))` it says:

> The expression 'c.SettlementNames.WhereLanguageId(1)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty').

Comment: EF Core (or any other o/r mapper) works on `IQueryable<T>` not on `IEnumerable<T>`. Change both `IEnumerable<T>` in `WhereLanguageId` to `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: And even when you fix the IEnumerable/IQueryable issue, I think that EF still doesn't know how to handle (=translate into SQL) your WhereLanguageId method - it will not read the definition of that method

Comment: SettlementNames is an ICollection. public virtual ICollection<SettlementName> SettlementNames { get; set; }  So I cannot use as IQueryable.  I don't know why this extension method not working in separate file. This is only a code separated to reuse.

Comment: You can't do that without third party extensions like LINQKit.

Comment: It has nothing to do with separate files. EF Core translates the query into a SQL statement and it does not know how to translate the `WhereLanguageId` function into SQL because it is a function unknown to EF Core.

Comment: But I have a very similar WhereLanguageId extension method in a separate method (but this is an IQueryable, because it is for a dbset, and the code snippet mentioned above is for IEnumerable because it is for a one to many relations.) That is the only different.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán, I can show how to do that with LINQKit, if you are ready to use third party extensions.